# accessing and downloading on demand resources iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, on-demand-resources

I am  trying to implement new iOS9 feature app thinning, I understood how tag an image and enable on demand resource in Xcode 7 but I don't understand how to implement NSBundleResourceRequest in my app, can someone help me, that would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check if the resources are available. Else download them.

Here is the `swift` code I use

```
let tags = NSSet(array: ["tag1","tag2"])
let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: tags as! Set<String>)
resourceRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler {(resourcesAvailable: Bool) -> Void in
    if resourcesAvailable {
        // Do something with the resources
    } else {
        resourceRequest.beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler {(err: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = err {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Do something with the resources
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also found [this guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-on-demand-resources-on-ios-and-tvos--cms-24929) very helpful.

Comment: hello roland i just used in my demo for localization like this but it downloads all tags at once can you help me out

Comment: You need to edit the tags array and only download the ones you need at that time.

Answer (score 5):

Most of information is available in Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSBundleResourceRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundleResourceRequest/initWithTags:bundle:).

Basically you need make this:

```
NSSet *tagsSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"resourceTag1", @"resourceTag2", nil];
NSBundleResourceRequest *request = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:tagsSet];
[request conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {
    if (resourcesAvailable) {
        // Start using resources.
    } else {
        [request beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                // Start using resources.
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```