# How to access Asset Catalog (images) after downloaded through NSBundleResourceRequest?

Tags: on-demand-resources

I cannot access images inside an asset catalog after it's been downloaded through NSBundleResourceRequest (on demand resource).

My code, say the image set name is "snow_4" with on demand resource tag "tag1"

```
NSBundleResourceRequest* resourceRequest = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc] initWithTags:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"tag1", nil]];

[resourceRequest conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(BOOL resourcesAvailable){
     // if resource is not available download it
     if (!resourcesAvailable) {
         [resourceRequest beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:
          ^(NSError * __nullable error){
              if(!error){                      
                  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"snow_4"]; // image is null
              }
          }];
     }else{             
         UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"snow_4"]; // image is null
     }
 }];
```

Below is my Disk Report, please note that [UIImage imageNamed:@"snow_3"] (marked as 'In Use') returns a correct object but not images that are marked as 'Downloaded'

[image: Disk Report]

Appreciating your time and help!

Thanks,
Mars

Comment: Check my answer [here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48327239/6534130

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `NSBundleResourceRequest` is not released early. Try to let `NSBundleResourceRequest` variable globally,
and access the image with `UIImage(named: "xxx", in: self.bundleReq.bundle, compatibleWith: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

do this

image = [UIImage imageNamaed:@"snow_4" inBundle:[resourceRequest bundle]];

Comment: Hi vince, thank you for your reply. I've tried it but it doesn't work. The resources are still marked as 'Downloaded' and cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

```
let tags = NSSet(array: ["tag1","tag2"])
let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: tags as! Set<String>)
resourceRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler {(resourcesAvailable: Bool) -> Void in
    if resourcesAvailable {
        // Do something with the resources
    } else {
        resourceRequest.beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler {(err: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = err {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Do something with the resources
            }
        }
    }
}
```